# Mac OsX sockets limit for TCP connections, how to increase?

Tags: macos, sockets, tcp, limit

I am writing a server program in Mac OSX using XCode 5.0 in a Late 2011 MBP, OS is a 10.8.5.
I am using cocoaasyncsockets (https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket). I tried the echoserver example that comes in the cocoaasyncsocket download.

I tried a load testing at it, and at about 2550 connections estabilished, it stopped accepting/estabilishing connections. I tried to increase that number, and I will be honest, I "may" have messed my configuration (mostly using sysctl -w calls, so when I booted it was back to its default), but as far as I got, the 2550 connections limit remained. 
When I rebooted and kept trying the next day, I noticed the new limit at which the same happened was of only 250 connections, and I could not get past that.

I also tried that on a mac mini 2011 (I never changed anything in any configuration of this mini, it is as vanilla as it gets), and the connection limit is 250 connections also.

I suppose the OS is limiting the maximum connections, and this is my question:
how do I increase the maximum allowed number of connections OSX allows?

I intended to get at least 32k tcp connections, and now I don't even know if it is possible.
Could this be an issue with my wifi router?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that the use of other resources is limiting the number of sockets you can handle simultaneously?

Comment: I have reviewed the blog entry, followed its steps (it was one of many tries I did on the first day, and I also tried it today), but the results didn't change. I also really don't think the use of other resources is the limiting factor, as the Mac is a 2011 model with 4GB Ram and have nothing else running (and besides, for a reason I cannot understand, yesterday I got 2.5k connections, today I can only get 250, same exact machine-why the reduction?).
I don't use NAT on my router.
I believe I saw someone reporting 10.5k connections on this same machine/OS (unfortunately I don't remember where).

Comment: @KillianDS The number of ephemeral ports isn't relevant. This is a server, not a client. It only needs one port.

Comment: Killian, if I understand this correctly, there is a listening port, and when it gets a connection it asks the OS for a free port, connect that incoming connection there, and keep listening in the original port.
The problem is that at some point the OS stops providing a free port, and I'd like to know how to increase the total number of ports the OS provides.
And if I don't understand this correctly, I will be REALLY REALLY happy if someone can shine a light on that for me.

Comment: @user3329949 No, you don't understand this correctly. When you accept a socket from a listening socket, you are presented with a new socket with the same local port number as the listening socket. Ephemeral ports are only used by clients when creating outbound connections, or by servers that deliberately ask for one for the listening socket.

Answer (score 3):

May be late still wanted to add to this..

exactly had the same problem. Just increment open files using ulimit -n to say 10000 and connect clients from multiple process solved the issue. I split 2500 connections to every process and could create 10k connections.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't change that on OSX.